# How to make videos download and play inside unity app?

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

Hello so I am trying to make online videos download on the android export app from unity and then play it back in the same app. so far I have used a plugin EasyMovieTexure asset for streaming online videos but cannot find a way to download videos and play them. I have searched and found that I can download the video with Android Application.persistentDataPath but I don't know how to use it and save the video file to a location on android. 
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way will be using System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes () to save all byte data from the WWW object. But this method actually need RAM to hold the whole file for a while. It doesn't work if the file is too big. if the file size is too big, you probably need another way to do the downloading and saving